# How to concatenate fields using lightning:dataTable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I would like to combine the **Account Name and Industry fields** and display the values. Can someone please help?

```
component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'Phone'},
                {label: 'Website', fieldName: 'Website', type: 'url '}
            ]);
```

I have tried `{label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'}` + `{label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'}` and all sort of combination but nothing seem to work. Can someone help here?

I.e I want to display like **Burlington Textile -> Textile**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @HarishSridhar. Why don't use standard features like formulas?

Comment: Hello @MartinLezer - I am getting these details by hitting an endpoint and my values are not being stored anywhere and am just displaying them on the go if user clicks a button. Above is an example which I just gave it for, but this is my real scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't create formulas in a data table. You would need to calculate a value based on your criteria, such as:

```
dataRows.forEach(row => row.nameAndIndustry = row.Name + ' ' + row.Industry);
```

`lightning-datatable` and `lightning:datatable` do not otherwise support expressions for fields.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of lightning datatable for this specific requirement you can use the code from slds.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/

Comment: Yes - I've done it using HTML tables - thanks.